# JComboBox not appearing in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, gridbaglayout

I am having a problem displaying the last JComboBox, i am using a GridBaGlayout
everything appears as i want it to except for the last component with names cat1,cat2 and cat3

I tried adding a `JLabel` into the end and setting it's `.weightx` property as `.REMAINDER` but even that label does not get displayed.

I tried changing the `.gridwidth` property as well but to no avail.

I also tried adding other combo boxes but they still don't appear even though they appear in their first occurrences, so I am guessing it's a column count error of some sort, but i didn't set any of that nor even know how that is set.

I am still a bit new to the `GridBaGLayout()` and I still couldn't figure out my problem, 
I tried looking up other codes and answers online but I just couldn't find my error!
can you help me please?

P.S. I just put in the main method for you to be able to test, this is called from another class, so it might have some starting errors (hope not);

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class selectioins implements ActionListener 
{
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    JButton searchB, viewB, newB;
    JTextField search1F,search2F,search3F;
    JComboBox logic1,logic2,logic3, cart1,cart2,cart3;

    String[] carterias = {"First name:","Last name"};
    String[] logic = {"Disabled","AND","OR","NOT"};

    char Type = 'c';
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      new selectioins('c');
    }
    public selectioins(char type) 
    {
        //##### Initialization #####
        String head = "";
        if(type=='c'){ head = "Customer"; Type = 'c';}
        if(type=='e'){ head = "Employee"; Type = 'e';}
        f = new JFrame(head +" Search");
        p = new JPanel();

        search1F = new JTextField();
        search2F = new JTextField();
        search3F = new JTextField();

        searchB = new JButton("Search");
        newB = new JButton("New entry");

        logic1 = new JComboBox(logic);
        logic2 = new JComboBox(logic);
        logic3 = new JComboBox(logic);
        cart1 = new JComboBox(carterias);
        cart2 = new JComboBox(carterias);
        cart3 = new JComboBox(carterias);

        searchB.addActionListener(this);
        newB.addActionListener(this);

        //##### layout settings #####
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc4f = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc4f.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc4f.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc4f.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc4f.weightx = 0.75;
        gbc4f.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);

        GridBagConstraints gbc4l =  (GridBagConstraints) gbc4f.clone();
        gbc4l.weightx = 0.1;
        gbc4l.gridwidth = 1;


        GridBagConstraints gbc4cmb = (GridBagConstraints) gbc4f.clone(); //ComboBox 
        gbc4cmb.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc4cmb.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gbc4cmb.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;


        //##### adding components #####
        p.add(new JLabel("Search for:"),gbc4l); p.add(search1F,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(new JLabel("in:"),gbc4l);         p.add(cart2,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(new JLabel(" 1"),gbc4f);          p.add(logic1,gbc4f);

        p.add(new JLabel("That has:"),gbc4l);   p.add(search2F,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(new JLabel("in:"),gbc4l);         p.add(cart2,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(new JLabel(" 11 "),gbc4f);            p.add(logic2,gbc4f);

        p.add(new JLabel("Also has:"),gbc4l);   p.add(search3F,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(new JLabel("in:"),gbc4l);         p.add(cart3,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(new JLabel("3 "),gbc4f);

        p.add(searchB,gbc4cmb);
        p.add(newB,gbc4cmb);


        //##### Containers finalizing #####
        f.add(p,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //f.setResizable(false);
        f.setBounds(600,400,400,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }




    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I assume that you would be better of by using "MiG Layout", which makes layouts in JFC/Swing much easier... http://www.miglayout.com/ (... that is unless you aren't forced to use GridBagLayout because no 3rd party libraries are allowed in your project or you are working on some kind of homework task and have no other choice.....)

Comment: @headcr4sh I'm way in this, and i want to get the hang of GridBagLayout first.. as well as i don't have much time to relearn another Layout manager since this is  a project due in less than 48h and still got things to be finialized. but thanks for the refrence, i am planning to learn it soon.

Comment: are you sure that you aren't using the same GBCs? The gbc4cmb looks like it was also used for adding search3F.

Comment: Make sure your constraints have the desired `gridx` and `gridy` values. These determine which cell in the grid the component is placed. The line `gbc4cmb.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;` is nonsense; it only compiles because everything is an `int` because Swing was created long before Java had typesafe enums.

Comment: @OliverWatkins the GBCs are according to their  position in the layout, i used the `gbc4cmb` for adding all the components in the middle of the row since it's `.gridwidth` property is set to relative
I grouped row as a paragraph on it's own to make it easier to dicern

Comment: read my answer below

Comment: @dish that means i'd have to set a GBC for each column as well as the first and land totaling over 6 GBCs, that will make things very messy and inefficient! i also seen many who did it without it..
My main concern here is why does it disappear? there should be 2 more component that should appear after the 3rd label added into the panel

Comment: You define 6 JComboBoxes, but don't put any values into the JComboBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I managed to fix it.

I removed the `GridBagLayout.RELATIVE` attribute and changed it to 1 in the gbc4cmb and it worked!

```
GridBagConstraints gbc4cmb = (GridBagConstraints) gbc4f.clone(); //ComboBox 
        gbc4cmb.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc4cmb.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gbc4cmb.gridwidth = 1;
```

Comment: Great! It's always nice to find such a small change that makes such a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't quite understand how GridBagLayout works. It needs constraints for each component. That means each component gets a different constraint. In your example you are using the same GridBagConstraint for adding different components (eg. gbc4cmb is used about 6 times!!).

In general a constraint should not be used more than once, otherwise you will have components overlapping each other (because they have the same x,y).

Comment: You may use the same GridBagConstraint for different JComponents.  You have to change the values of the GBC for each JComponent, but you can use the same GBC.  I find using one GBC confusing, but it is allowed.

Comment: i am aware of that point, and since the x,y are not set it defaults and auto switches, otherwise they'd all be on the same cell, am i wrong?

Comment: The layout manager makes a copy of the constraints object provided when a component is added. Thus you can create one and simply update the coordinates (and other constraints as applicable) as you proceed to add each component. I tend to name mine `c` and reuse the same local variable name for each. I also tend to use `c.gridx += 1` or `c.gridy += 1` to set the coordinates as I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a `BoxLayout` and panels for each row in your GUI, where each panel uses a `FlowLayout`. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot example]

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelectionsAlternative {
    private static final String[] CRITERIA = {"First name", "Last name"};
    private static final String[] OPERATORS = {"Disabled", "AND", "OR", "NOT"};

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SelectionsAlternative().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        addCriterion(mainPanel);
        addOperator(mainPanel);
        addCriterion(mainPanel);
        addOperator(mainPanel);
        addCriterion(mainPanel);

        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(width, 10);
        Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(width, height);
        mainPanel.add(new Box.Filler(minimumSize, preferredSize, preferredSize));

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addCriterion(JPanel mainPanel) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Search for:"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(28));
        panel.add(new JLabel("in:"));
        panel.add(new JComboBox<>(CRITERIA));
        mainPanel.add(panel);
    }

    private void addOperator(JPanel mainPanel) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        panel.add(new JComboBox<>(OPERATORS));
        mainPanel.add(panel);
    }
}
```